# How can I read the first two bytes of a .zip file to confirm that the appropriate magic number is present?

Tags: java, byte, compression, huffman-code

I'm trying to read in a .zip file that holds a compressed .txt file. How can I check for the magic number 0x00BC? Thanks.

Edit: Sorry, should have specified that I'm trying to do this in java.

Comment: it might help http://bmsi.com/java/ZipLock.java

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: Is not the magic number CAFE BABE for class files? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Comment: Magic number for zip is PK. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: @Fedy2 Whoops, disregard that. Sorry about that, dumb mistake. I guess that's just my immediate thought whenever I think of magic numbers. Question still applies though. Thanks for correcting that.

Comment: You want to read the first two bytes of the zip file or the first two of the contained file?

Comment: Well the .txt was compressed into a .zip file. So the zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two bytes from the ZIP file:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FILE NAME);
byte b1 = (byte)is.read();
byte b2 = (byte)is.read();
is.close();
```

First two bytes from the first compressed file:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FILE NAME);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
zis.getNextEntry();
byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
zis.read(bytes, 0, 2);
zis.close();
```